# Why is my program throwing java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3F?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to tokenize a piece of Chinese text with Stanford NLP but the program throws exceptions all the time.

I tried different ways to load the properties file but they didn't work.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class Spider {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            StanfordCoreNLP ppl;
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream in = Spider.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
            prop.load(in);
            ppl = new StanfordCoreNLP(prop);
            Annotation doc = new Annotation("浮云白日，山川庄严温柔。");
            ppl.annotate(doc);
            ppl.prettyPrint(doc, System.out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The exceptions are as follows:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3F   at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
>     at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>     at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1588)
>     at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2642)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1473)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1505)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2939)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:286)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:270)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.(ClassifierCombiner.java:142)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.(NERClassifierCombiner.java:108)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator.(NERCombinerAnnotator.java:125)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:68)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$5(StanfordCoreNLP.java:523)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
>     at Spider.main(Spider.java:13)
>   edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't
>   load classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:70)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$5(StanfordCoreNLP.java:523)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
>     at Spider.main(Spider.java:13) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   Couldn't load classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:296)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:270)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.(ClassifierCombiner.java:142)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.(NERClassifierCombiner.java:108)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator.(NERCombinerAnnotator.java:125)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:68)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class
>   edu.stanford.nlp.classify.LinearClassifier (java.util.ArrayList is in
>   module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
>   edu.stanford.nlp.classify.LinearClassifier is in unnamed module of
>   loader 'app')     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.loadClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1095)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1473)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1505)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1495)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.getClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1141)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:292)
>     ... 14 more

Comment: Have you searched for existing questions on SO? [java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3F when I customize serialization process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556629/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-3f-when-i-customize-seriali) might be a duplicate, or others

Comment: http://inaved-momin.blogspot.com/2012/08/understanding-javaiostreamcorruptedexce.html

Comment: @MarekR: this is the [third such question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.io.StreamCorruptedException%3A+invalid+type+code%3A+3F), can you pick one as a canonical for closing duplicates?

Comment: Those existing questions don't seem to give me any assistance. I turned code from initializing ppl to the last line in the "try" block into comment and no errors were reported. But once I validated the initializing statement all these exceptions set in.

Comment: What jars do you have in your CLASSPATH

Comment: You mean the environmental variables? None.

Comment: When you run this program, what is in the CLASSPATH.  Also could you provide more details about how you are running this program.